# get file from angularjs spring boot maven project

Tags: angularjs

i would like to load a file from a folder located in src/main/resources called download, i tried the following code:

html:

```
<a ng-href="fileUrl" download="fileName">download File</a></br>
```

FileController.js:

```
$scope.fileUrl= 'download/file.txt';
```

where the folder download is located in src/main/ressoure.

How can access to this file?

Comment: i think that ng-href doesn't turn the value of fileUrl declared in FileController

Answer (score 0):

i changed ng-href to href with the value {{fileUrl}} as the following:

download File